# Concatenate two huge files in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I have two std::ofstream text files of a hundred plus megs each and I want to concatenate them. Using fstreams to store the data to create a single file usually ends up with an out of memory error because the size is too big.

Is there any way of merging them faster than O(n)?

File 1 (160MB):

```
0 1 3 5
7 9 11 13
...
...
9187653 9187655 9187657 9187659
```

File 2 (120MB):

```
a b c d e f g h i j
a b c d e f g h j i
a b c d e f g i h j
a b c d e f g i j h
...
...
j i h g f e d c b a
```

Merged (380MB):

```
0 1 3 5
7 9 11 13
...
...
9187653 9187655 9187657 9187659 
a b c d e f g h i j
a b c d e f g h j i
a b c d e f g i h j
a b c d e f g i j h
...
...
j i h g f e d c b a
```

File generation:

```
std::ofstream a_file ( "file1.txt" );
std::ofstream b_file ( "file2.txt" );

    while(//whatever){
          a_file << num << endl;
    }

    while(//whatever){
          b_file << character << endl;
    }

    // merge them here, doesn't matter if output is one of them or a new file
    a_file.close();
    b_file.close();
```

Comment: you should at least explain what you mean by merging

Comment: Merge files of size n faster than O(n)? How do you imagine that would happen?

Comment: Do you want a file as output or only the "merge" (whatever you mean by that) as a temporary representation in your program (destroyed on exit)?

Comment: (Can you post the basic structure of your code? I kind of suspect that you are manually forcing your program to buffer the entire input file before appending it to the output file.)

Comment: @us2012 I can't imagine it and that's why I'm posting here.

Comment: Edited with the format of the files. I'd edit the creation in a second.

Comment: A better word rather than "merge" would be "concatenate" or "append".

Comment: Your current code doesn't *read* anything, it just writes, so I'm not sure how your description of "merging two files" applies here.

Comment: I know it doesn't *read* anything. I am asking if there is an alternative to the trivial way of istream::read with O(n). It's right there in the question.

Comment: Honestly, I think this is an XY problem. If the question is exactly 'I have two files a and b and I want to concatenate them in a new file c' there is not much more to this. However, depending on your needs there might be filesystem tricks, or even application layer tricks that do this without problem. You could perfectly write a 'multifile' stream class that just continues to the next file when EOF of one file is reached. This would meet your requirements of being faster than `O(n)` but is only a viable solution in *very* specific circumstances.

Comment: Why can't you write to the same stream in both while loops?

Comment: I'm not able to understand where the point is in all of this, but anyway I would write O(n+m), being that there are two input files

Comment: @KillianDS Could you please write that as an answer?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to do any processing, and just want to concatenate two files to make a third, you can do this very simply by streaming the files' buffers:

```
std::ifstream if_a("a.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
std::ifstream if_b("b.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
std::ofstream of_c("c.txt", std::ios_base::binary);

of_c << if_a.rdbuf() << if_b.rdbuf();
```

I have tried this sort of thing with files of up to 100Mb in the past and had no problems.  You effectively let C++ and the libraries handle any buffering that's required.  It also means that you don't need to worry about file positions if your files get *really* big.

An alternative is if you just wanted to copy `b.txt` onto the end of `a.txt`, in which case you would need to open `a.txt` with the append flag, and seek to the end:

```
std::ofstream of_a("a.txt", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::app);
std::ifstream if_b("b.txt", std::ios_base::binary);

of_a.seekp(0, std::ios_base::end);
of_a << if_b.rdbuf();
```

---

How these methods work is by passing the `std::streambuf` of the input streams to the `operator<<` of the output stream, one of the overrides of which takes a `streambuf` parameter ([operator<<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)).  As mentioned in that link, in the case where there are no errors, the `streambuf` is inserted unformatted into the output stream until the end of file.

Comment: After running some tests I found this solution to be the best. Its timing is very variable but manages to go faster than manual reads in most cases, plus is short and sweet.

Comment: Great answer. You can add `std::ios_base::ate` to the `ofstream::open` call, which opens the file with the output position already `at end`. This saves you the `seekp` call.

Comment: Isn't the `seekp` call reduntant because of `std::ios_base::app`?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way of merging them faster than O(n)?

That would mean you would process the data without passing through it even once. You cannot interpret it for merging without reading it at least once (short answer: no).

For reading the data, you should consider un-buffered reads (look at std::fstream::read).

Comment: +1 for `istream::read` (similarly, `ostream::write` seems like a logical choice for writing).

Comment: This seems to be the most sensible answer, I've been looking at gnu_cat and they do the same in a per-char basis. Looking at my code, is there any algorithm better for what I'm doing than the two-file merge approach?

Comment: Is `fstream::read` un-buffered? I thought that any buffering was a part of the underlying `streambuf` class, in this case `filebuf`, which has methods specifically to handle internal buffering.

Comment: It is unbuffered. Buffering (in this context) doesn't refer to reading from rdbuf - it refers to: (1) read bytes from rdbuf into <local buffer> (within std::istream), then (2) if it's possible to interpret <local buffer> as <data type>, (3) construct <data type>, then (4) deallocate <local buffer>, (5) advance rdbuf state/read position and (6) return <data type> to client. By using read, we're only performing steps (1) and (5).

Comment: With linked-lists, you can concatenate one linked-list to another in O(1) time, by setting the tail-pointer of the first list to point to the first node in the second list.  With files, a similar trick ought to be possible, at least in principle -- all of the data is already on the disk, so it would just be a matter of tweaking the metadata so that the second file's contents are now seen to be a continuation of the first file's contents rather than the data of a separate file. This would require explicit support from the filesystem, though, and I'm not aware of any filesystems that have it. :(

Answer (score 3):

On Windows:-

```
system ("copy File1+File2 OutputFile");
```

on Linux:-

```
system ("cat File1 File2 > OutputFile");
```

But the answer is simple - don't read the whole file into memory! Read the input files in small blocks:-

```
void Cat (input_file, output_file)
{
  while ((bytes_read = read_data (input_file, buffer, buffer_size)) != 0)
  { 
    write_data (output_file, buffer, bytes_read);
  }
}

int main ()
{
   output_file = open output file

   input_file = open input file1
   Cat (input_file, output_file)
   close input_file

   input_file = open input file2
   Cat (input_file, output_file)
   close input_file
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It really depends whether you wish to use "pure" C++ for this, personally at the cost of portability I would be tempted to write:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::ostringstream command;

    command << "cat "; // Linux Only, command for Windows is slightly different

    for (int i = 2; i < argc; ++i) { command << argv[i] << " "; }

    command << "> ";

    command << argv[1];

    return system(command.str().c_str());
}
```

Is it good C++ code ? No, not really (non-portable and does not escape command arguments).

But it'll get you way ahead of where you are standing now.

As for a "real" C++ solution, with all the ugliness that streams could manage...

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

static size_t const BufferSize = 8192; // 8 KB

void appendFile(std::string const& outFile, std::string const& inFile) {
    std::ofstream out(outFile, std::ios_base::app |
                               std::ios_base::binary |
                               std::ios_base::out);

    std::ifstream in(inFile, std::ios_base::binary |
                             std::ios_base::in);

    std::vector<char> buffer(BufferSize);
    while (in.read(&buffer[0], buffer.size())) {
        out.write(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
    }

    // Fails when "read" encounters EOF,
    // but potentially still writes *some* bytes to buffer!
    out.write(&buffer[0], in.gcount());
}
```