# How to concatenate split files without new line and replicate original file?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

```
void merge(std::string& filesPath,   std::string& outPutFilePath) {

       namespace fs = std::filesystem;
       std::set<fs::path> files_to_merge;
       std::ofstream merged_file;
       fs::path split_path = fs::path(filesPath);
       for (const auto& file : fs::directory_iterator(split_path)) {
            files_to_merge.insert((fs::path)file);
            }
  
      std::ofstream ofile(outPutFilePath,std::ios::out|std::ios::app|std::ios::binary);
      ofile.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);
      for (auto& file : files_to_merge) {
      std::ifstream ifile(file, std::ios::in |  std::ios::binary);
      if (!ifile.is_open())
         {
          throw invalid_file("could not read file: ");
          break;
        }
     ifile.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);
     std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char> (ifile),
          std::istream_iterator<char>(),
          std::ostream_iterator<char> (ofile));
    //ofile << ifile.rdbuf();
      }

    }
```

split_path is path to splits of bigger file. The code actually merges. The problem is it inserts a new line between 2 file parts.The insertion of new line may not problem for human beings. But when the merged file is encrypted file, the decryption algorithm fails due the inserted new line[s].
Is there a way to replicate original file when merging?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue: [**Test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22f3018a1e23d7d7). Are you sure that your mistake was not somewhere else?

Comment: @Scheff Thanks. Yes I am sure. I tested with not split-ed file. The only issue to make aware is the splited and merged file is not asci or base64. It is encrypted(not human readable, may be binary) file, in case there may be special issues to such file types.

Comment: Alternatively, I tried this [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc714101287225ec). For binary files, I wouldn't use formatted I/O. (Stream iterators are based on it.) I saw your commented `ofile << ifile.rdbuf();` which I found also in another Q/A [SO: Concatenate two huge files in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19567371/7478597) which should result in unformatted I/O as well.

Comment: @Scheff Is same with ofile << ifile.rdbuf(); It is the first approach I tried with.

Comment: Strange. What platform are you on? (OS, compiler)

Comment: @Scheff Linux(ubuntu)

Comment: I ran my tests on Ubuntu as well: [**Coliru runs Ubuntu**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8a70bb8d5801be3)

Comment: Maybe, you search the bug at the wrong location. Are you sure that the split was done correctly? What if the wrong newlines are already in the splitted files?

Comment: I solved by reading to std:: string then writing back to output file from string